# Django - Loading a full image on separate page

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to put a hyperlink on my image thumbnail which would take the user to a full size image. but I keep on getting an error.

here as it shows, scribblemedia is a ForeignKey to scribble

## models.py

```
class ScribbleMedia(models.Model):
     media = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)
     def __unicode__(self):
      return self.media
     def find_typecheck(self):
        filename = self.media.name
        try:
           ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
           imgcheck=['jpg','jpeg','png','gif','tiff','bmp']
           if ext in imgcheck :
              chk='image'
           else:
              chk='other'
        except Exception:
           chk='not supported'
        return chk

class Scribble(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
     body = models.TextField()
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     media = models.ForeignKey(ScribbleMedia)
     def __unicode__(self):
      return u'%s, %s' % (self.user.username, self.media)
```

## views.py

```
@login_required
def image_page(request,pk):
    img=get_object_or_404(ScribbleMedia,pk=pk)
    image=img.media
    variables= RequestContext(request,{
    'image': image
    })
    return render_to_response('image_page.html',variables)
```

## urls.py

```
(r"^image/(\d+)/$", image_page),
```

## image_page.html

```
{% if  image %}
    <img src= {{ image.url }} />
```

This is the page where the image thumbnail is available

## scribble_page.html

```
{% if scribble.media.media %}
                {% if scribble.media.find_typecheck == 'image' %}
                    {% thumbnail scribble.media.media.url "700x500" crop="center" as im %}
                            <a href="/image/{{ scribble.media.pk }}/" target="_blank"><img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}"></a>
                    {% endthumbnail %}
                {% else %}
                    do something else
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
```

It keeps on giving me the following error:

TemplateSyntaxError at /image/2/
Unclosed tag 'if'. Looking for one of: elif, else, endif

Comment: :) yeah I was just waiting for stackoverflow to let me accept your answer. They wanted me to wait for 10 minutes or something before I accepted it. I dont know why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The if statements in your scribble_page.html are fine.  You need to close your if block in your image_page.html template...

```
{% if  image %}
  <img src="{{ image.url }}" /> <!-- Also note the added quotations... -->
{% endif %}  <!-- This is the line you need to add -->
```

Comment: I am so sorry! I was just pulling my hair over this for two days and I couldn't see what a simple thing I was missing. I really appreciate it :) thank you!

Comment: No worries.  Happens to me too.